# How would civilization differ if silicate glass wasn't so useful?

Tags: alternate-history, chemistry, ancient-history, element

(This is a "hard sci-fi" chemistry question.)

Silicate glass is malleable when hot, stiff at human-compatible temperatures, transparent, and chemically inert. It's cheap and easy to make, perhaps even by [lucky accident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_glass). As such, it gave humans indoor sunlight, bottles, lenses, chemistry equipment, fiberglass, etc.

In a universe where silicon is much less helpful, with properties no better than boron or germanium (whichever is worse for any given application), how would humanity reach those technological milestones (if at all)? What would they create instead, and how available are the raw materials?

(All other elements retain their existing properties. I am not marking this `hard-science`, but references for particularly interesting claims would be appreciated. )

Comment: This would need a book to answer.  Focus on one particular use of silicon (eg optical glass) and it might be answerable, otherwise it is really multiple questions in one post, one for every current use of silicon.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 Is focus on one form of silicon small enough, or should I break this down into a dozen separate questions?

Comment: It depends partially on what the worldbuilding context is here.  Are you writing a novel set in the equivalent of today's world and are trying to describe how the world is different, or creating a pseudo-medieval tabletop roleplaying game and writing the equipment table or what?  Part of the problem with making an entire element "bad at everything" is that being bad at one thing tends to make it useful for something else. For example, glassware is good for many lab applications because it is fairly non-reactive, if it now is reactive then there will be other uses for it.

Comment: Are you assuming that the only thing affected by this is silicate glass? If the properties of silicon were different enough to cause glass to to be weaker/harder to work with, surely this would also mean significant differences in the most common minerals of the earth's crust, silicates, feldspars, etc. If these were weaker or softer, it would drastically change the landscape, alter building construction, and much more.

Comment: Pure silica glass, aka fused quartz, is actually quite hard to make, because it only melts at around 2000 °C (4000 °F). Windows and bottles are not made of that; they are made of [soda–lime glass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soda–lime_glass), which contains about 70 to 75% silica, about 15% sodium oxide, about 10% calcium oxide, and possibly some alumina. *This* is the cheap and easy to make material, melting at around 700 °C (1300 °F). (And please note that it is silic**a**, silicon oxide, not silic**ate**.) (Germanium oxide can be melted into a transparent glass just like silicon oxide.)

Comment: @AlexP The expression of ceramic components as pure oxides, e.g. silica is only a convention for convenience of formulation. The coordination environment of the silicon atoms in a typical glass (e.g. soda-lime-silica) or ceramic (e.g. porcelain) is silicate-like, not silica-like. You can see the difference in e.g. MAS-NMR spectroscopy.

Comment: @barbecue is correct here. Many of the same structural properties of silicon dioxide that make silicate glass useful are also significant to the geophysics of a large number of minerals, which would in turn have a major impact on geography and the usability of many types of stone as building materials (I would expect granite and sandstone especially to be _much_ less useful).

Comment: You don't need to alter the physical properties of silicates to make them less useful.  Just make them much less abundant (more expensive).

Comment: @Theodore they're the primary component of Earth's crust. Making them significantly rare would be no less drastic a change than changing their properties.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff I was thinking more along the lines of choosing a setting on a planet with less silicates.

Comment: @Theodore ...which will lead to drastic differences that are no different from the result of changing the physical properties of silicates.

Comment: One thing you may not be aware of, optical flats in metrology to verify for flat surfaces. I am not sure what you would replace them with but without a way to verify that a reference surface is sufficiently flat, that rules out a lot of technological development. I don't know if you can replace that with some other transparent non-glass materials because they have to be very flat and precise. It is used with a monochromatic light source...which also requires glass.

Comment: @Theodore but silicates are *ubiquitous*: "They are the largest and most important class of minerals and make up approximately [90 percent of Earth's crust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicate_mineral)."

Comment: As the asker, I'm being asked to narrow the question down "to one problem", focus on just one property of silicon. The problem with that request is: the problem I'm concerned about is exactly that it has SO MANY uses. The question I really wanted to ask is "Is Silicon's Huge Breadth of Useful Properties Overpowered?" I've already narrowed the question to exclude silicon chips, solar panels, silicones, etc. Narrowing any further wouldn't come close to the answers I'm looking for.

Answer (score 16):

Where the clarity of glass isn't required, there are plenty of alternatives... lots of ceramics out there and not all glazed finishes require silicon. It might make stuff like [enamel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitreous_enamel) impossible to make, but the rules are yours and not mine so I can't be certain there. There are other minerals that can be drawn into fibers suitable for reinforcing things if not conducting light ([basalt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basalt_fiber) and [carbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_fibers) spring to mind, though the latter was invented for the production of electric lightbulbs which is much harder in your world).

For basic optical things you can use mirrors. Newton was credited with making the [first reflecting telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_reflector), but the possibilities of curved mirrors were understood in the [Book of Optics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Optics) which was written a thousand years ago. Reflecting microscopes have been a thing for nearly a hundred years (there's a potentially relevant article in [Science](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.112.2910.381) from 1950 which is paywalled because of *course* it is) but in the absense of glass lenses they might well have been investigated much earlier.

The lack of windows though, that's much more serious. Not only does housing become gloomier and colder, but working hours for many kinds of task become sharply limited in places where there's sometimes a bit too much rain or wind to have open windows and artificial light isn't a suitable replacement for daylight. And speaking of artificial light: no lightbulbs, and use of lamps and lanterns will be sharply constrained by things like wind and drafts and will be somewhat more hazardous. Early transparent plastics were notoriously flammable, and things like LEDs are less than a hundred years old so that's a broad swathe of time with inadequate lighting.

Whilst there are natural transparent minerals like [calcite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcite) and [fluorite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorite) they are crystalline rather than glassy, which means mass production is difficult because large crystals have to be grown sloooooowly and cannot be nicely blown and shaped and moulded but must be ground. Fluorite is also soluble, so whilst it is an excellent materials for optical lenses you do have to treat it carefully. Calcite has odd [optical doubling effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birefringence) too, so even if you could grow it quickly and cheaply it is not a drop-in replacement for glass. Neither is conveniently inert like glass.

[Transparent ceramics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparent_ceramics) are much better, but they're awkward things to work with which is why they didn't pop up in the real world until the 60s when GE made some lights with [clear alumina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_oxide) instead of glass. Some things like synthetic [spinel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinel) have only very recently been successfully turned into products.

Acrylic resins and polycarbonates and other clear polymers might get you there eventually (alongside things like [LEDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode#Discoveries_and_early_devices) which started appearing at the turn of the last century), being a little older than transparent ceramics and much easier to work with, but they're still modern materials that are the end product of a mature industrial civilization build on hundreds of years of scientific advancement, all of which would be slowed by the absense of inert clear materials. There's nothing to say that they *couldn't* be discovered in boring-silicon-world, but it'll be much harder.

Comment: Weren't early windows made of thin *leather*? To let (some) light in but keep air out?

Comment: @MooingDuck I did wonder about that, but it is very much a "better than nothing" sort of option, and I'd be worrying about the rats nibbling it. You _might_ be able to do something similar with waxed or oiled cloth, but from memory this tends to get mold or algae growth that makes it more and more opaque as time goes on. With a sufficiently advanced solarpunk tech base you can use [transparent wood](https://www.usda.gov/media/blog/2020/10/01/transparent-wood-could-be-window-future)...

Comment: Carbon-arc lamps don't require glass (or fused quartz, or any other form of transparent envelope).

Comment: The article you linked has a copy available freely from archive.org: https://scholar.archive.org/work/jft4lueojbdfhlc4pblq3i4fgq/access/wayback/http://www.ganino.com/games/Science/science%20magazine%201940-1957/root/data/Science_1940-1957/pdf/1950_v112_n2910/p2910_0381.pdf

Answer (score 8):

Bit of a frame challenge, because it is too long for a comment:

Your civilization would drastically differ from now... because there would be no civilization. In fact, there probably wouldn't be life at all, of if it were, it would be unrecognizable.

The issue here is that to change the fundamental properties of silica (or other compound of silicon) you would need to drastically change physical laws. For it not being transparent strong inert material it would need to stop being a covalent crystal. For that you would need to either change the electronegativity of silicon and/or oxygen, or change the geometry of the chemical bonds. Either would require the change in how fundamental forces work...

One could think you could instead prevent silica from being discovered. But that is also problematic. Both silicon and oxygen are extremely common elements, and decreasing silicon content on Earth would change the average density of the planet and thus our gravity (I don't have to explain why messing with oxygen rates would be a bad idea). And if you don't remove silicon from the environment, silica WILL be discovered rather sooner than later. It is after all a possible byproduct in metalurgy. Not to mention there are natural sources of it.

The only believable answer for why woud civilization is not using glass would be if they decided they don't want to use it, for example for religious reasons. But that is kinda far fetched, as silica is extremely useful material.

Comment: the asker did ask for not hard science

Comment: @user253751 But he did ask for "hard sci-fi" and chemistry. Neither allows magic, which is the only plausable means to explain his changes to the world.

Answer (score 5):

Daily life wouldn't be all that different:

- indoor sunlight - an open window, with a metal screen to keep out bugs, can work almost as well
- bottles - containers can be made from wood, stone, leather, etc. With the right coatings you can make things hold water and other liquids, resist corrosion, etc.
- chemistry equipment - as with containers, lack of glass won't stop progress, just slow it down a little
- fiberglass - a modern material and there are plenty of alternatives, whether for building boats or insulating buildings

And eventually people would figure out how to make clear plastics. That eventually gives you clear windows in houses, and more importantly windows for cars and airplanes. Plus it gives you clear bottles and a lot of other things. Not quite as good - e.g., most (if not all, I'm not a chemist) plastics will not be as impervious to chemicals as the best glass, but good enough for most purposes.

But there is one key difference: **lenses**

Without glass, you don't have:

- microscopes - seriously affecting the development of biology, medicine and some other scientific fields, as well as microelectronics.
- telescopes - seriously affecting the development of astrophysics, from Galileo onward.

Medicine will be the most affected. Without visible support for germs as well as in-depth examination of lower level biological functions - blood cells, cancer, you name it - medical science, and as a result the average lifespan, will not increase nearly as rapidly as it has in the past few centuries.

The computer revolution would only very slowly progress beyond 1950s mainframes, because it will be much harder to develop integrated circuits without microscopes and related technology. The microcomputer revolution depends on integrated circuits to make machines small and affordable. And on the other end, supercomputers depend on integrated circuits for high speed because speed is related to size.

Comment: This could be combined with the answer about mirror-optics. Since mirror-telescopes could probably solve the last problem on your list.

Comment: "an open window, with a metal screen to keep out bugs, can work almost as well" - you must live in San Diego :)

Comment: Microscopes and telescopes can be made from curved mirrors.

Comment: Antique microscopes used drops of water as lenses, or spherically ground crystals for high-power lenses. (Alum has a high RI). Telescopes can use mirrors. For buig telescopes, mirrors are actually better.

Comment: Before mass production of moulded glassware, our Victorian ancestors used pottery (stoneware) bottles and jars. It was cheaper to throw and fire clay containers, than hand-made glassware.

Comment: Integrated circuits at one point (IIRC circa 1985) used electron-beam lithography not light lithography. And of course one can see IC details better with an electron microscope than with a light microscope.

Comment: @nigel222 The very first ICs were literally components wired together inside a "chip". Then they moved (pretty quickly) to photolithography and it was possible to decap a chip and look at it under a microscope and figure out how it worked. Only later did features get so small (to increase speed and complexity) that electron-beams were needed.

Comment: How does a mesh screen keep out an 8 month winter? When it's also darker making daylight is even more precious? According to your profile you live in Silver Springs, Maryland where water barely freezes during the winter but about half the world isn't so lucky.

Comment: Winter - close the windows, light some candles. Not ideal but people would do that at night anyway no matter where they are. But during the warmer parts of the year, screens will let you have the windows open because that will keep the bugs out but let light in. Remember, until a few hundred years ago only the rich had window glass at all!

Comment: That's greatly narrows the scope of the the specific words used: "Daily life wouldn't be that different: indoor sunlight - an open window, with a metal screen to keep out bugs, can work almost as well". You're kind of just brushing off the significance of the advent of artificial light.

Comment: @DKNguyen and how is artificial light going to develop (beyond candles/basic oil lamps, at least) without glass for lanterns, bulbs, etc?

On an unrelated point, I see another problem in that if silicate glass weren't so useful, the physics/chemistry changes needed to make that so might inhibit silicon semiconductor development too.

Comment: @DoktorJ That's exactly my point. It's not. Artificial light has greatly changed the world but this answer is saying that without artificial light, "daily life wouldn't be that different."

Comment: I actually didn't say anything about artificial light. What I said was that you could still have sunlight during the day - that was a thing long before plate glass became affordable. As far as artificial light, yes incandescent bulbs are *really* dependent on glass (most clear plastic would melt, and unenclosed the filament won't last long) and fluorescent would have problems too. But while less efficient, there were arc lamps and I'm reasonably certain there would be other technologies born out of necessity. Unfortunately, LED would a big technological jump, but could eventually happen.

Comment: I'm equating light during the winter (even if we're only talking about daylight hours) with either windows or artificial light, and without glass you have neither. So while life during daylight hours might not change a lot of for those down south, but that's not the case for people up north during the winter.

Comment: I don't think LEDs would happen to be honest. Because without glass you don't have things like optical flats which are required to verify flatness for reference surfaces in metrology which required for semiconductors. Let alone lasers and the light sources required to make LEDs in the first place. You mentioned arc lamps...is glass not absolutely necessary for those? I don't see how since you still need to enclose the ionizing gas somehow.

Comment: Looking around I see a carbon arc lamp does not necessitate glass.

Comment: @DKNguyen Correct. Carbon arc lamps can last longer with glass but they work perfectly well without glass.

Answer (score 4):

### You'd lose a lot of ceramics too

Most ceramics feature a silica-rich silicate glass matrix with a dispersed crystalline solid phase. The classic one is porcelain, but even most high fired stoneware is somewhat glassy.

### Sintered oxides provide one workaround.

The good news is that there is a workaround: You could make sintered oxide ceramics and glasses. They would be much more expensive, but you can do it. For niche applications, you'd need to make more pure silica glass than we do today (you still have that, right?).

### You'd probably have a lot more composite cement materials

Composite non-glassy ceramics are going to be much more useful in this environment. Short fibre reinforced cement, etc. It won't be translucent, though.

## In summary

Civilisation would still advance, but it would probably have a much slower progression through the early modern and Victorian eras.

Answer (score 4):

People used thin layers of horn for windows. Or parchment. Or paper. Something they did not discover was that you could make [wood transparent](https://www.discovermagazine.com/technology/transparent-wood-is-a-surprisingly-versatile-material) with little more than sodium hydroxide.

You could use mirrors instead of lenses, or grind lenses out of clear crystal.

Comment: The important part of the "transparent wood" is mostly just some resin, which needs to be transparent by itself. So I guess the discovery of these resins is what helps us here.

Answer (score 2):

Currently we can make synthetic crystals in small quantities, at extreme expense.  We can also find crystals in nature but they are rare enough to be expensive.  Since you are already altering the laws of physics to make Silica worse, how about you also make sapphire or diamond easier to make/find?  Have large natural crystal formations that your society has learned to etch/carve/carefully-split into useful shapes to replace glass.

1. Clear windows are common, but never uniform in size as they have to match the size and shape of the polished/fractured crystal they were made from.  Skylights are more common to let in more light as ground floor windows are usually made from metal screens, or thin paper. The metal and paper can be bigger and in more consistent shapes, with the lack of light being accounted for in the odd-shaped crystal skylights.
2. Bottles are made of wood or metal in most cases
3. Instead of one generic material for petri dishes and chemistry sets; chemists and biologists have multiple sets of different materials for different uses, (various types of crystals, and metals, eventually some plastic.)

Answer (score 1):

Look at Japan's history. For most of it, Japan only imported small quantities of glass and made relatively little of it domestically.  The Japanese found alternate ways to do many of the things the rest of the world used glass for.

Answer (score -1):

We would HAVE to evolve faster. Our brains would be used more and we'd never even need mobile phones or computers. We would still find a way to make them but they would just be options for fun stuff like music and games and porn when we wanted our brains to rest a bit.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).